# Using strcmp gives me segmentation fault (cs50 runoff problem)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

In the vote function i can't figure out why if i enter a different voter's name, it gives me a segmentation faul instead of returning false.

```
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    if (strlen(name) > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < voter_count ; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(candidates[i].name , name) == 0)
            {
                preferences[voter][rank] = i;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
```

I checked other codes for the same problem set and with the same code, they didn't get any wrong messages from the checker.

Comment: Need a [mcve], not just a single function. What is `copy`?

Comment: Also clean up your indentation to help make your code easier to follow. Tools like `clang-format` or GNU `indent` can help if your IDE/editor doesn't have its own reformatting feature.

Comment: My bad about the copy variable i just forgot to put it there, i fixed it just now, i intend to fix the indentation and everything else after i get rid of the seg fault error, any idea of what might be wrong ?

Comment: `for (int i = 0 ; i < voter_count ; i++)` Loop counter is # of voters. Array is array of **candidates**...

Comment: Fix those other issues _before_ worrying about the segfault.

Comment: @Fe2O3 it turns out that's the mistake, thank you !

Comment: Readability is important. Especially for beginners. Therefore always maintain correct indentation and general formatting while editing your code. Don't do it "after XY is done". It will make XY harder to be done due to poor readability.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the variable `copy` in the function indicates a new global variable has been added. That is expressly forbidden by the spec and will not pass `check50`.

> You should not modify anything else in `plurality.c` other than the implementations of the `vote` and `print_winner` functions (and the inclusion of additional header files, if you’d like).

Comment: the 'copy' variable is just a mistake, it's from an other thing i tried earlier, i fixed it just now, but still the same seg fault again if i enter a different voter name!